# javascript: changing the name attribute dynamically

Tags: javascript, dynamic, input

I have this script I'm working on and there's no errors on it but I want to add some functions on it like when I click the button it adds but I want the name attribute of the input text to be changed too.

Here's my script:

> javascript:

```
var a = 1;
function add() {

    var fContent = document.getElementById('1');
    var sContent = document.getElementById('2');
    if (a <= 10) {
        a++;
        var objTo = document.getElementById('m');
        var divtest = document.createElement("div");
        divtest.innerHTML = (sContent.innerHTML + a + fContent.innerHTML);
        alert(divtest.innerHTML); 
        objTo.appendChild(divtest);
    }
}
```

> html:

```
<input type="button" onclick="add();" value="+" />
<div id="m">
<div id="1">
<input type="text" name="f">
<input type="text" name="l">
<input type="text" name="m">
</div>
<div id="2"></div>
</div>
```

> OUTPUT:

```
2
<input type="text" name="f">
<input type="text" name="l">
<input type="text" name="m">
```

> EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
2
<input type="text" name="f2">
<input type="text" name="l2">
<input type="text" name="m2">
```

and so on...

Comment: What about using name="f[]"? - this will create an array of values

Comment: i already did that it wont work.

Comment: _innerHTML_ is string, so you can use regexp and replace value for _name_ attribute. Also now your _sContent.innerHTML_ always empty

Comment: I don't get it. Where exactly do you try to change the `name` attributes? Why do you expect them to be any different?

Comment: why not use jquery, it will be so much easier. I can provide you the jquery solution.

Comment: @Grundy the sContent is always empty cause the script gonna copy the fContent and place it to sContent.

Comment: @basilikum i change the name attirbutes so it gonna work on my server side codes.

Comment: you are missing code which actually changes name: element.setAttribute('name', 'newName');

Comment: @william.eyidi i don't like to use any jquery. im so sorry. if you can proivide a pure javascript then I will accept that. thank you

Comment: @Myel, your script, not copy _fContent_ to _sContent_, only to new div

Comment: @Grundy That's ridiculously bad advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not doing anything to change the name attributes. Trying to make those changes with html concatenation will get you into trouble. This will get you started:

```js
(function() {

  var a = 1;

  // get a reference to the container
  var container = document.getElementById("m");
  // get a reference to the first row of input
  var base = container.children[0];  
  
  document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(e) {

    if(++a > 10) return;
    
    // clone the first row of input
    var clone = base.cloneNode(1);
    
    // change the number text by setting the span's textContent
    clone.children[0].textContent = a;
    // set the names of the input fields
    clone.children[1].name = "f" + a;
    clone.children[2].name = "l" + a;
    clone.children[3].name = "m" + a;
    
    // add the new row to the container
    container.appendChild(clone);
    
    console.log(clone);

  });

})();
```

```html
<button type="button">+</button>
<div id="m">
  <div><span>1</span><input type="text" name="f1"><input type="text" name="l1"><input type="text" name="m1"></div>
</div>
```

If you'd rather create the elements from scratch...

```js
(function() {

  var a = 1;

  // get a reference to the container
  var container = document.getElementById("m");    
  var input;
  var span;
  var div;
  
  document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(e) {

    if(++a > 10) return;
    
    // create our div
    div = document.createElement("div");
    
    // create and append our span
    span = document.createElement("span");
    span.textContent = a;
    div.appendChild(span);
    
    // create and append inputs    
    ["f","l","m"].forEach(function(n){
       input = document.createElement("input");
       input.name = n + a;
       div.appendChild(input);            
    });
                
    // append our div
    container.appendChild(div);
    
    console.log(div);

  });

})();
```

```html
<button type="button">+</button>
<div id="m">
  <div><span>1</span><input type="text" name="f1"><input type="text" name="l1"><input type="text" name="m1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: is it possible without using a clone?

Comment: @Myel Sure, create the elements from scratch. I've added an example.