# i have invoice table but i want post data dynamically

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

i  have invoice table where add multiple row but input type name is different

like  vegproduct,vegproduct2,vegproduct3,vegproduct4..

this is post data but i want this using loopchange post value dynamically

```
$data = $this->input->post('vegproduct');
$data = $this->input->post('vegproduct2');
$data = $this->input->post('vegproduct3');
```

if you any confusion otherwise i will you share website

Thanks

Comment: so what you have tried?

Comment: please check this link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30039442/javascript-changing-the-name-attribute-dynamically

Comment: Use loop with increment ?

Comment: don't make name different take their values in array

Comment: Better off just using <input type="whatever" name="vegproduct[]"> and handling that array in the controller.